# Load images from URL in infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, gallery, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to load images from an API and first filling whole page. When scrolling I want to make more requests and just keep loading in new images.

So I've tried:

```
var infiniteScroll = new InfiniteScroll( grid, {
        path: 'https://api.giphy.com/v1/stickers/random/z8FVOIy1P7ZwgFXjuHmeZtuAFpBlRYJr',
        append: '.grid__item',
        status: '.page-load-status',
        history: false,
        loadOnScroll: true,
});
```

Will infinite scroll do an AJAX call? I want to use vanilla javascript/ES6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of InfiniteScroll library you can go with Vinilla javascript implementation.

Listen for the `scroll` event in window and load images from api based on that.

I have use the [debounce](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) the scroll event as it's fired thousand of time with vertical scroll.

```
var currentScrollPosition = window.scrollY;
var timeToWait = 1000; // No of millisecond to wait before call loadImages function.
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};

function loadImages(e){
   if((currentScrollPosition + 500) < window.scrollY){
   currentScrollPosition = window.scrollY;
    console.log('dfdf');
   // Do you image loading here
   }
}
window.onscroll = debounce(loadImages,timeToWait);
```

jsFiddle demo - http://jsfiddle.net/vkxhnd8y/

Comment: I removed the + 500 in the if((currentScrollPosition + 500) < window.scrollY) and it works. Do you have any advice for filling up the page at first? Without scrolling